# Performance implications of function calls in PSM1 Modules

Tags: performance, powershell, module

I have a function that does a find/replace on text files, and it has worked well for some time. Until I needed to process a 12 million line file.
My initial code used Get-Content and Write-Content, and with the massive file it was going to take hours to process, not to mention the memory implications of loading 12 million lines into RAM.
So, I wrote a little test script to compare that approach vs Stream Reader/Writer. And Streaming looked like it was going to be a massive performance improvement, dropping processing to 30 seconds. I then added a `.Replace()` on each line, and total processing time only went up to maybe a minute. All good. So then I went to implement it in my real code, and performance has tanked again. That code is a PS1 that loads a number of PSM1 files. The function to do the find replace is in one of those PSM1 files, and that code calls functions in another PSM1. The test script was everything in a single small PS1.
Given that my test script didn't use a function call at all, I tested that first, so there is a function in the PS1 that gets called 12 million times from the loop in the same PS1. No real performance impact.

So, my thought then was that calling a function in one PSM1 that then calls a function in another PSM1 (12 million times) might be the issue. So I made a dummy function (which just returns the passed string, as if no replacement was needed) in the same PSM1 as the loop. And that is orders of magnitude slower.

I have not tested this with everything in the PS1, mostly because these functions are needed in three different scripts with very different argument requirements, so implementing it with Modules really made a lot of sense logistically, and changing that would be a massive undertaking.

That said, is there a known performance hit when calling a function that lives in a Module? I was under the impression that once the Modules are loaded, it's basically the same as if it was all in a single PS1, but perhaps not? FWIW, I am not using NameSpaces. All of my functions just have function name prefix on the noun side to avoid conflicts.

I also can't really post minimally functional code very easily since that's in a single file that doesn't exhibit the behavior. If there is no obvious answer to someone I guess my next step is to implement the test script with some modules, but that's not really apples to apples either, since my real modules are rather large.

To add a little context: When the function (in a PSM1) does not call a function and simply sets `$writeLine = $originalLine` total time is 15 seconds.
When doing an actual find and replace inline (no call to a function) like this `$writeLine = $originalLine.Replace($replace, $with)` total processing time is 16 seconds.
When calling a function in the same PSM1 that just returns the original string total time is 17 minutes.
But again, when it's all in a PS1 file with no modules, calling a function has minimal impact. So it certainly seems like calling a function in a PSM1, even from a function in that same PSM1, has a massive performance overhead.

And more context:
I moved the replace function in the test script into a Module. No appreciable change. So I moved the main code, including the loop, into a function in that module, and called it from the main script. Again, no real change. Both took around 15 seconds.
So, it's not something innate in Modules. That then begs the question, what could I be doing in my other modules that would trigger this behavior? This modules are 3000-10,000 lines of code, so there is a lot going on. Hopefully someone has some insight as to best practices with modules to mitigate this. And hopefully it's not "Don't use big modules". ;)

Final update:
It seems it IS a function of how big the module is. I deleted all the other functions in the Module that contains the loop, and performance is fine, 17 seconds. So, basically even as of PS5.0, the implementation of modules is pretty useless for anything large. Rather disconcerting. I wonder if the same would be true if all the functions where in a single file, and PowerShell performance with large files with lots of functions is just bad? Anyone have any experience down this road?

Comment: You completely closed PowerShell before testing the PS1 right? Otherwise the modules are still loaded in the session from before they were changed, and it doesn't load the updated code.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Yes, all tests are run from a shortcut that launches the PS1 with arguments. So the processing environment is "fresh" every time.

Comment: Glad you found that Enter key. :)

Comment: Are you sure that it's the size of the module rather than some other implementation detail(s)? I would rule that out first.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart No, not sure yet. I am working on a short term solution for the current deadline, and then I am going to build a test script that times function calls into different Modules, one that has a lot of lines but few functions, one that has a lot of functions but few lines, one that has both, and one that has neither. I hope I can quantify things a bit. But that's for the weekend I think.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart One implementation detail is the fact that I have lots of functions, and each one has it's own Export-ModuleMember. I haven't used wildcards at all. But I would THINK that this impacts readability and code maintenance, rather than performance. In any case, I hope to test things this week, the weekend ended up focused on other tasks.

Comment: Also, I am not dot sourcing, I am loading the module, and loading it into a main script. The entire tool is run from a shortcut, never from the ISE or PS console, so no autoloading. The shortcut is specifically not loading a profile, as well.